# Firestore search array-contains-any for multiple values

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

If I have a collection like this:

```
Logos:
  Logo1:
   colors: ["red","black"]
   shapes: ["square","circle"]
  Logo2:
   colors: ["red","yellow"]
   shapes: ["square"]
```

And if I want to search logos that are red or black, I would do the following:

```
db.collection("Logos").where("colors", "array-contains-any", ["red", "black"]).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        //do stuff
    })
```

And that would get me all the Logos in my collection that contain the color red or black. However, how would I be able to do a search for logos that are `(red OR black) AND (circle OR square)` but I cannot combine multiple `array-contains-any` operators.

Is this even possible in Cloud Firestore? If not is there any alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From the Firestore documentation:

> You can use at most one `in`, `not-in`, or `array-contains-any` clause per query. You can't combine `in,` not-in`, and` array-contains-any` in the same query.

The workaround is to combine the values you want to check on into a single array, but I don't think that'll work here since you'd then be looking to combine `AND` and `OR` conditions on that array.

So the only option seems to be to perform one condition directly on the database, and do the rest of the filtering in your application code.